# "command not found" error using filetype plugin

Tags: filetype, error, linux-ubuntu

I am trying to add `filetype plugin indent on` to my `vimrc`, and I'm getting the error `filetype: command not found`. I tried searching but can't find a solution. I have the full `vim` package installed (not just tiny). Any ideas? Thanks!

(Ubuntu 20.10)

Comment: Start with [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604), and triple-check `:version`/`command -v vim`

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing looks more like a Bash error than a Vim error. For example, here is what I get when I run your command from Bash:

```bash
$ filetype plugin indent on
-bash: filetype: command not found
```

Note that error identifier (i.e., `EXXX`) characteristic of Vim error messages does not appear in the output. Here is what I get when I try to run an invalid command (e.g., `:invalid`) from Vim:

```
E492: Not an editor command: invalid
```

Looking through the Vim source we can see that if Vim produced such a message we would expect to see an [E371 identifier](https://github.com/vim/vim/search?p=2&q=%22command+not+found%22). As a sanity check, from the [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) link that user D. Ben Knoble provided in [his comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29695/command-not-found-error-using-filetype-plugin#comment54605_29695) to your question, open Vim in a bare state:

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE -N
```

Then query the `filetype` option by executing the command `:filetype`. Here is the result on my machine:

```
filetype detection:OFF  plugin:OFF  indent:OFF
```

If this works, then it is a pretty good indication that the problem is stemming from your vimrc and the debugging article provided can guide you further along that process.

Comment: Indeed, perhaps OP mistakenly wrote `source ~/.vimrc` at a bash prompt instead of `:source ~/.vimrc` in vim

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have shared this here as I figured this out. It's been a while since I developed regularly, so I'm rediscovering these silly errors. :-/ Thanks for your detailed answer. I hope it helps someone else, as I searched all over and couldn't find a solution.